# Deploying Dockerized SpringBoot Microservices with Eureka to AWS Fargate

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, aws-fargate

I have a couple of dockerized microservices that register with Eureka & works on my local env with Docker Compose.
The same when deployed to AWS Fargate via its CLI (using the same Compose file), fails.
I also tried changing the reference to Eureka, in clients, from (which works with Docker Compose)
*eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:8761/eureka*
to 
*eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka*
The Docker Compose file is shown below:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
 eureka:
  image: navraj28/eureka
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
  networks:
    ecsfs:
      aliases:
       - eureka

 facade-service:
  image: navraj28/facade-service
  ports:
   - "8100:8100"
  environment:
   - eureka.host=eureka
   - eureka.client.enabled='true'
   - eureka.instance.preferIpAddress='true'
  depends_on:
   - eureka
   - geri-service
  logging:
    driver: awslogs 
    options:
      awslogs-group: ai-facade
      awslogs-region: us-east-1
      awslogs-stream-prefix: facade-service      
  networks:
    ecsfs:

 geri-service:
  image: navraj28/geri-service
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
  environment:
   - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/credentials.json   
   - eureka.host=eureka
   - eureka.client.enabled='true'
   - eureka.instance.preferIpAddress='true'
  depends_on:
   - eureka
  logging:
    driver: awslogs 
    options:
      awslogs-group: ai-facade
      awslogs-region: us-east-1
      awslogs-stream-prefix: geri-service         
  networks:
    ecsfs:
networks:
  ecsfs:
```

Anyone had success with this combo? And the error log messages just don't make sense:
[image]